# puppet enterprise vagrant r10k sandbox development environment with geppetto

Tags: vagrant, sandbox, puppet

I have setup a working sandbox with

- Virtualbox
- vagrant
- vagrant-pe_build
- vagrant-hosts

This builds a perfect master agent sandbox using `r10k` to deploy a puppet sandbox environment.  I am creating by hand a `sshfs` to mount the `root@master.local:/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/environments/sandbox/modules/` environment.  I want to use `geppetto` to import all the projects and export it as a working set for the team.  `r10k` uses the concept of a remote "cache" to fetch stored objects which eliminates duplication and speeds it up.  It also leaves the clone on a "(no branch)" checkout.

When I go to import the project via geppetto the cache is not on my hypervisor where I am editing.  So it essentially non functional.

I can try to fix the clone, but I am hoping there is a better automated solution before I script something.

1. Does anyone have a better methods for sshfs?  I tried vagrant-sshfs but that didn't work
2. Is there a better way to use r10k to create a working copy?
3. Is there a better sandbox environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `sshfs`, you should consider using Vagrant/Virtualbox's shared folders feature.

http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/basic_usage.html